# Set lastTextFieldReturnKeyType with nativescript-IQKeyboardManager

Tags: typescript, nativescript, iqkeyboardmanager

I want to set the `lastTextFieldReturnKeyType` to `DONE`. I think I have to use `IQKeyboardReturnKeyHandler`, but I don't know how in Angular/typescript. Does anyone have any experience with this? I was unable to find it in https://github.com/tjvantoll/nativescript-IQKeyboardManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=6npT5b) is how you would do it with TypeScript.

```
declare var UIReturnKeyType, IQKeyboardReturnKeyHandler;

// Inside page loaded event
const returnKeyHandler = new IQKeyboardReturnKeyHandler(page.ios);
returnKeyHandler.lastTextFieldReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done;
(<any>page)._returnKeyHandler = returnKeyHandler;
```

Incase of Angular, you may inject the `Page` in the constructor and use the same loaded event.